# How to make a web service that consume about 500 RSS and save new items in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have a project that I need to make a service that we will add to it about 500 RSS for different sites and we want this service to collect new RSS feeds from these sources and save Title and URL in my SQL Server database.

How can I determine the best architecture design, and what codes would help me in that?

Answer (score 5):

These indications are not specific to your stack (`c#`, `asp.net`), but I would definitely **not recommend doing anything from the request-response cycle of your web app**. It must be done in an asynchronous fashion, but results can be served from the database that you populate with the feed entries.

1. It's likely that you'll have to
   build an architecture where you
   *poll each feed every X minutes*. Whether it's using a `cron` job, or
   a daemon that runs continuously,
   you'll have to poll each feed one
   after other other (or with some kind
   of concurrency, but the design is
   the same). Please make use of the
   HTTP headers likes [Etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and
   If-Modified to avoid polling data
   that hasn't been updated.
2. Then, you will need to parse the
   feeds themselves. It's very likely
   that you'll have to support
   *different flavors of RSS and Atom*, but most parsers actually support
   both.1.
3. Finally, you'll have to store the
   entries and, more importantly before
   you insert them, make sure you
   haven't already added them. You
   should use the the `id` or `guid`
   for the entries, but it's likely
   that you'll have to use your own
   system too (links, hash...) because
   many feeds do not have these.

If you want to reduce the amount of polling that you'll have to do, while still keeping timely results, you'll have to implement [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) for the feeds which support it.

If you don't want to deal with any of the numerous issues exposed earlier (polling in a timely maner, parsing content, diffing to keep uniqueness of entries...), I would recommand using [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) as it deals with all the pain points.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go into details about implementation or detailed architecture here (mostly from lack of time at this particular moment), but I will say this:

- It's not the *web service* that should consume the RSS feeds, it should merely be responsible of *spawning the work to do so asynchronously*.
- You should not use threads from the `ThreadPool` to do this, for two reasons. One is that the work can be assumed to be more or less time consuming (`ThreadPool` is recommended primarily for short-running tasks), and, perhaps more important, `ThreadPool` threads are used to serve incoming web requests; don't want to compete with that.